# What does the phrase "a little while,and ye shall see me"refer to in John 16:16

Tags: john, word-study

John 16:16 (KJV)

> 16 A little while, and ye shall not see me:  and again, ***a little while, and ye shall see me***, because I go to the Father

Could this be in reference to:

1)Christ's resurrection on the third day and being seen by the disciples

2)Christ second coming to judge the world

3)Outpouring of the Holy Spirit

Answer (score 1):

Christ is reminding the disciples of His death and departure (*A little while, and ye shall not see me*), but He also gives encouragement by telling them that afterwards (*and again, a little while*) He will be translated to the a different place (with *the Father*) wherein He will be with them eternally (*and ye shall see me*).

In this section of John, Jesus is preparing His disciples for His crucifixion and death.  He wants them to remain steadfast and hopeful through the trials that come.  This is the purpose of the verses that follow:

John 16:19–20 (KJV 1900)

> *Now Jesus knew that they were desirous to ask him, and said unto them, Do ye inquire among yourselves of that I said, A little while,
>   and ye shall not see me: and again, a little while, and ye shall see
>   me? Verily, verily, I say unto you, That ye shall weep and lament, but
>   the world shall rejoice: and ye shall be sorrowful, but your sorrow
>   shall be turned into joy*

.

Answer (score 1):

"A little while and ye shall not see me" = his death

> "Then took they the body of Jesus and wound it in linen clothes with the spices, as the manner of the Jews is to bury." (John 19:40, KJV)

"a little while and ye shall see me" = his resurrection

> "But Thomas, one of the twelve, called Didymus, was not with them when Jesus came. The other disciples therefore said unto him, We have seen the Lord." (John 20:24-25, KJV)